# Problema na criação de chaves estrangeiras MySQL

Tags: relacionamento, mysql

Estou tentando implementar um relacionamento 1:1 entre a tabela Funcionario e a tabela Usuario, no MySQL Workbench, mas ao gerar o Diagrama vejo que o relacionamento sempre se mantém em 1:n, mesmo com a constraint UNIQUE na chave estrangeira.

```
CREATE TABLE `funcionario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `senha` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `nivel` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL,
  `datacadastro` DATE NOT NULL,
  `id_funcionario` int(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  INDEX `fk_id_funcionario` (`id_funcionario` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

alter table `usuario`
add foreign key (`id_funcionario`) references `funcionario`(`id`);
```

Como posso especificar que, para esse caso, o relacionamento deve ser 1:1?

Comment: Se o relacionamento é 1:1, por que você não une as duas tabelas?

Comment: Pensei em unir, mas serão extrema minoria os funcionários que terão usuários cadastrados, logo sobrarão muitos campos nulos em uma tabela unificada.

Comment: Se a chave estrangeira em usuário é `UNIQUE` e ela é `NOT NULL`, não tem como a tabela ficar 1:n.

Comment: Também pensei dessa forma, mas quando faço o "Reverse Engineer" pra gerar o diagrama, ele exibe o relacionamento como se fosse 1:n

Comment: Veja se essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365959/how-to-make-one-to-one-relationship-eer-diagram-in-mysql-workbench-6-3e) lhe ajuda.